# How to add python support to already installed postgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have postgreSQL version 8.3 installed on an ubuntu machine. This was installed via apt get. When I was trying to source a database dump that has some plsql functions written, I got the following error -

```
could not access file "$libdir/plpython": No such file or directory
```

When I tried to enable python support for a particular database, I got yet another error -

```
$ createlang plpythonu <dbname> -U postgres
createlang: language installation failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython": No such file or directory
```

Is there a way that I can add support for python without having to reinstall postgreSQL?

Comment: Why was this closed instead of being migrated to say, serverfault?

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython-8.3
```

or for postgresql 8.4:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython-8.4
```

Answer (score 4):

Install `postgresql-plpython-8.3`?